# MySQL access denied for user connection with JDBC

Tags: permissions, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I just did a new install on Ubuntu 16.04 and MySQL 5.7. Im able to connect on the command line by my application running in Tomcat is getting access denied for the same user. Here is how  I created my user:

```
create user 'myuser'@'localhost' identified by 'mypassword';
grant all on myschema.* to 'invenio'@'myuser';
```

I can login from the command line and get access to everything:

```
 mysql -u myuser -p
```

But, my application gets access denied for the same user/password

```
show grants;

| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myschema`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' |
```

The user privileges look strange:

```
SELECT * FROM  information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES;
`myuser'@'localhost'          | def           | USAGE                   | NO
```

This is the error from Tomcat:

```
    Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' 
    (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
```

Any lead to what Im missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message that your Tomcat application spits out when it fails during a connection? It could either be a connection error or a credential error.

Comment: Updated with the sql error

Comment: can you post your connection string? maybe you have chars in password that are not properly escaped?
possibly similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946111/jdbc-connection-to-remote-mysql-db-fails

Comment: Try logging in as the database's root user. If it works, then that might point to a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

ok.. my fault(well someones fault) the password in the properties file was not what it was suppose to be..

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem might be with the DB connection rather than the mysql user, I would make sure that your app is able to properly commnunicate with MySQL.
I would also try install phpmyadmin and try to log in with the user you created and see what happens.

Comment: How do you know it’s a connection issue when the error is not provided?

Comment: JakeGould I imagined that with the amount of information given and since he was able to login from the command line. Try reading the databases from mysql command line with the users you created. Also, somewhere I read that mysql-connector.jar has to be in the classpath for the connection to work, You can try that as well

Comment: The error states, “Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' 
    (using password: YES)” This all means the connection is made, but  the user is somehow being denied access. This is not a connection issue.